# Impossible sequence of events

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm trying to track down a mysterious iterator problem in a `for` loop. I get an error in the iterator's `operator!=` which generally means that the iterators being compared do not belong to the same container. Tracing into Microsoft's implementation of the library, `operator!=` calls `operator==` where this test is true:

```
    bool operator==(const _Myiter& _Right) const
        {   // test for iterator equality
 #if _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL == 2
        if (this->_Getcont() == 0
            || this->_Getcont() != _Right._Getcont())
            {   // report error
            _DEBUG_ERROR("list iterators incompatible");
```

In an attempt to get more information I wrote this little function to replace my `!=` in the `for` loop:

```
template<typename iter>
bool bang_equal(const iter & left, const iter & right)
{
   static int count = 0;
   auto p1 = left._Getcont();
   auto p2 = right._Getcont();
   ATLTRACE("Iterator comparison left _Getcont()=%p right _Getcont()=%p %d\n", p1, p2, ++count);
   MemoryBarrier();
   bool b = left != right;
   MemoryBarrier();
   auto p3 = left._Getcont();
   auto p4 = right._Getcont();
   ATLTRACE("                    left _Getcont()=%p right _Getcont()=%p %d\n", p3, p4, ++count);
   return b;
}
```

Here's where it gets interesting. I still get the error in the expression `left != right` and the debugger stops there, but either the first `ATLTRACE` has been skipped or the second one has run ahead of time! The debugger output has both lines, and the value of `count` as shown by the debugger matches the last line of output.

```
Iterator comparison left _Getcont()=07D0B2C8 right _Getcont()=07D0B2C8 2984
                    left _Getcont()=07D0B2C8 right _Getcont()=07D0B2C8 2985
Myprog.exe has triggered a breakpoint.
```

Looking at the disassembly window shows the instructions in the expected order. I'm stumped. What might be happening?

Comment: Show the code where you're using !=. 99.9% or more of weird errors are user errors, not implementation errors.

Comment: Mark, I know we don't need to start from the basics with you, but humor me. I see no explicit breakpoint in your code, so I assume this is a breakpoint you added with the debugger. Have you tried doing "Rebuild All"? And are you trying this on a Debug or a Release build?

Comment: I detect a disturbance in the force, like that of a group of data being clobbered by an array overrun screaming and then becoming suddenly silent.  My guess is you have a memory corruption bug elsewhere in your code causing this behavior :)

Comment: @NikBougalis, the breakpoint is in the `_DEBUG_ERROR` code: `::_CrtDbgBreak();`. This is a Debug build, and yes I did a Rebuild All. I'll do it again just to be sure.

Comment: @Michael: +1 for the star wars reference.  Also, a promising, if unlikely(Mark knows what he's doing right?) theory.

Comment: We all get tunnel vision every now and then.  Occam's razor and such - it never hurts to start with the easy stuff.

Comment: @SebastianRedl, the line that calls `bang_equal` is totally unremarkable: `for(iter = m_pWatchList->begin(); bang_equal(iter, m_pWatchList->end()); )`

Comment: @MarkRansom Then the loop body would be the interesting part. This is where any iterator-invalidating or memory-clobbering code is most likely to be.

Comment: @Mark interesting... I see nothing obviously wrong or potentially weird here. Are the `MemoryBarrier` calls serving a reason or did you add them for testing purposes?

Comment: If you consistently get the error at the same counter value, you can stop at the right moment and trace the execution line by line.

Comment: @n.m., I added the counter hoping that would be the case, but it isn't.

Comment: @NikBougalis, I added the MemoryBarrier calls to ensure that nothing is being reordered. It probably wasn't necessary but I'm being paranoid at this point. P.S. the rebuild didn't change anything.

Comment: Rebuild All may not be enough. Manually delete all files in target .exe folder, just to be extra sure (this saved more than once).

Comment: Also, copy the project's source files to another folder and build it there, to be double-extra sure.

Comment: Also, what happens if `left != right` line is replaced with `DebugBreak()`?

Comment: Mark, can you manual `DebugBreak` *before* and *after* the call? I'm just curious to see if both those will be called before the breakpoint from the CRT.

Comment: Maybe, if it look like it's called outside your bang-function, it **is called outside your bang-function**.  I.e. is operator== called outside the area where you think it's called?  Maybe it happens in another place where you think it does (i.e. if not the for loop contidion, maybe something inside the loop boils down to it ... can you breakpoint in operator==)?

Comment: @Dialecticus, thanks for that suggestion - it led me to figure out what's happening.

Answer (score 12):

Finally figured it out. The Microsoft function `_Debug_message` displays a dialog box asking if you want to Abort, Retry (debug), or Ignore the error. While the dialog box is displayed the message pump is still running, allowing other activity to take place. My function was being called again and this time it ran to completion, generating lots of debug output in the process. If I put an explicit breakpoint on the `_DEBUG_ERROR` line in the library code I catch the error without additional execution in the background. Looking back at the debug output with the benefit of hindsight I can see that the expected error output was indeed there, just buried so far that I never saw it.

Comment: Ah... I should have figured this out. I've been bitten by this before. Horrible design on Microsoft's part.

Comment: I remember now being in the same situation... more than once.

Answer (score 3):

My intuition tells me that Occam's razor is the most likely explanation here: Specifically that you're invalidating the iterator during iteration. The fact that you don't have a `++iter` in the for loop further emphasizes that it's not a straight up iteration over every element.

It's probably not directly inside the loop, but the container is likely aliased somewhere within a call chain being called from the loop body - those are pretty easy mistakes to make and absolutely brutal to diagnose. You should at least print the size of the container at every iteration.

If you have access to Linux and a small enough part of code that reproduces the problem you could utilize valgrind to help you hunt down this as well.

Comment: Or you can just set a hardware breakpoint that triggers when the memory you are interested in is changed ;)

Comment: @Nik Bougalis The OP indicated that the element in question changes each run through, so I don't think a data breakpoint will be helpful here.