# How to stop at the first assert failed in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

How to stop at the first assert failed in Visual Studio?

When I debug, for each assert that fails I get pop-up windows
one on top of the other. But I don't want that behaviour,
I need the program to stop at the first failed assert,
so that I can debug from there.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: If you provide your own assert handler you can set a breakpoint in it.

Comment: Does your program have more than 1 thread?

Comment: To understand how this comes about see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17027382/impossible-sequence-of-events

Comment: @drescherjm yes there are more threads

Comment: Just in case - modern answer is probably here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1151175/10141885

Answer (score 10):

1. Make sure that you have the Native debugger enabled: Select your project in Solution Explorer, then select *Debug* > *YourProject Properties* (at the bottom). Choose *Debug* from the menu on the left, then under *Enable Debuggers* make sure the type is either *Mixed* or *Native*.
2. Make sure you're breaking on assert failures. Go to:

VS 2015: *Menu->Debug->Windows->Exception Settings*

Pre-VS 2015: *Debug* > *Exceptions*, expand *Win32 Exceptions*, and check *Assert Failed*:

[image]

Comment: cannot find assertion failed in my vs2010

Comment: In vs2015 the exception list is found in Menu->Debug->Windows->Exception Settings

Comment: Can you update your answer (so it covers both versions)?

Comment: In VS2017 I only see "Debug" not "Debugging" in the Properties window, "Debugger Type" not "Enable Debuggers", and setting Debugger Type to either Native Only or Mixed doesn't enable me to catch the assertion.

Comment: I think the better question is *why is this not on by default!?* ...Also I am using VS2019 and I cannot find this option.

Comment: I have this setting checked, but still the debugger just ends the program at `assert(false)` and alike. It does stop on access violation though.